Merge query is failing on sybase 16.0 version
I am trying to run below merge query in sybase 16.0 but it's failing with error

SQL Error [102] [42000]: incorrect syntax near '('.

merge into account_balance( id , account_name) as G 
using SELECT (?, ?) AS D( id , account_name) 
ON D.account_number=G.account_number 
when not matched then 
insert ( id , account_name) values ( D.id , D.account_name)
when matched then 
update set G.id = D.id,G.account_name = D.account_name

What does this error mean ? is this command not supported in sybase 16.0 version but documentation says otherwise.

Assuming OP is using Sybase (now SAP) ASE ...
tl;dr - the documentation is wrong.
Sybase ASE documentation was always a bit of hit-or-miss; after SAP bought Sybase they (SAP) have managed to escalate the term 'crappy documentation' to new heights; case in point, the merge statement ...
NOTE: the following was derived from a) reviewing the merge statement in other RDBMS products and b) some trial-n-error testing.
First issue: there is no column list in the into clause; column references are handled by other clauses:
--------
-- replace this:

merge into account_balance( id , account_name) as G

---------
-- with this:

merge into account_balance as G

Second issue: documentation uses ? to (not so clearly) designate the location where actual data values are to be supplied; these are the values that will be used in the resulting insert or update:
--------
-- replace this:

using SELECT (?, ?)

---------
-- with this:

using SELECT (3, 'name3')

Third issue: when using a derived table in the using clause it is necessary to wrap the derived table (aka sub-query) in parens; also, the data values are not wrapped in parens:
--------
-- replace this:

using SELECT (3, 'name3') AS D( id , account_name)

---------
-- with this:

using (SELECT 3, 'name3') AS D( id , account_name)

Fourth issue: columns referenced in the on clause must be defined in the using clause (OP's derived table in this case); in this case we need to provide a value and column reference for the join column account_number:
--------
-- replace this:

using (SELECT 3, 'name3') AS D( id , account_name)

---------
-- with this:

using (SELECT 3, 'name3', 'acct3') AS D( id , account_name, account_number)

I'm going to assume OP wants to populate the account_number column so the insert clause will need to be expanded to include the account_number column:
--------
-- replace this:

insert ( id , account_name) values ( D.id , D.account_name)

---------
-- with this:

insert ( id , account_name, account_number) values ( D.id , D.account_name, D.account_number)

Pulling these changes together we get the following merge statement:
merge into account_balance as G
using (SELECT 3,'name3','acct3') AS D (id,account_name,account_number)
ON    D.account_number = G.account_number
when  not matched then 
      insert (  id,  account_name,  account_number)
      values (D.id,D.account_name,D.account_number)
when  matched then
      update set G.id           = D.id, 
                 G.account_name = D.account_name


Taking for a test drive:
Create our table:
create table account_balance
(id             int
,account_name   varchar(100)
,account_number varchar(100)
)
go

select * from account_balance
go

 id account_name account_number 
 -- ------------ -------------- 

(0 rows affected)

merge that results in an insert:
merge into account_balance as G
using (SELECT 3,'name3','acct3') AS D (id,account_name,account_number)
ON    D.account_number = G.account_number
when  not matched then 
      insert (  id,  account_name,  account_number)
      values (D.id,D.account_name,D.account_number)
when  matched then
      update set G.id           = D.id, 
                 G.account_name = D.account_name
go

select * from account_balance
go

 id account_name account_number 
 -- ------------ -------------- 
  3 name3        acct3

(1 row affected)

merge that results in an update (id: 3 => 5; account_name: name3 => name5):
merge into account_balance as G
using (SELECT 5,'name5','acct3') AS D (id,account_name,account_number)
ON    D.account_number = G.account_number
when  not matched then 
      insert (  id,  account_name,  account_number)
      values (D.id,D.account_name,D.account_number)
when  matched then
      update set G.id           = D.id, 
                 G.account_name = D.account_name
go

select * from account_balance
go

 id account_name account_number 
 -- ------------ -------------- 
  5 name5        acct3

(1 row affected)

NOTE: tested with ASE 16.0 SP04 PL04

thanks for the answer. You have provided hard-coded values, I need to use it with prepared statement so how can I provide parameters in above query using jdbc prepared statement. If I replace hard-coded values with ? Then I need to provide column names also with account_balance table

Thanks , I took the clue from your answer by replacing your hard coded values with ? and set the parameters and it worked. Accepting your answer

Yeah, I'm familiar with the use of question marks in building prepared statements, and it may be that the person who wrote this part of the manual was coming from a developer/prepare-statement background.  Most SQL examples I find useful deal with actual values, and I'm assuming anyone with experience writing a prepared statement knows how to convert such examples into using the question mark references.  For the benefit of those who may come across this Q&A in the future you may want to consider adding your own answer that shows your final solution. Regards.

Could you please help me with this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78784695/sybase-merge-query-with-where-clause-in-insert-or-skip-the-insert-on-condition
