Sybase ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybLob
I am trying to save String of size 1500 characters in Sybase table which has a column of TEXT datatype, however I am facing error as below
ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybLob

So my question is why above error is coming and for String of varying length of upto 2k which  is the recommended datatype in sybase 16.
